# Setting MS-Word three column header in PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I am creating a Word document from a PowerShell script. How can I create a three column header and fill it with string values?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/13/use-powershell-to-create-a-word-table-that-shows-fonts.aspx

Comment: thanks alot ,adding three columns in the header is not working. At your link table is added into body which works fine for me but not in header.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include an example of it not working?  Be sure to include the output.

Comment: sorry i don't have one ,i want to automate it .Its actually a feature of ms-office which can be done manully

Comment: You can't make the header 2-column or 3-column.  You have to trick Word by putting a 1x3 table into the header, and turning off all the table lines.  This is easy to do manually, so why are you saying it won't work programmatically?  Include example code, please.

Comment: i am new to power-shell word doc automation user2654818  so if u have something to start with where i can know how to put different header on each page and how to include table in header programmatically do help  me out.